# Order SQL-table by transposing and counting of individual row entries?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, sql-order-by, transpose

I'm currently trying to give my very limited SQL-skillset a refresher by trying to sort the following example table (random example I pulled from the top of my hat, so nothing makes any sense.) by counts of each entry. The ... entries denote an indefinite amount of rows/columns. The goal is to get a table that automatically turns every entry for "Digested" and "Played with" into a counted row-entry.

Source table (Name TEST-TABLE):

| Animal | Digested | Played with |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Treats | Fake bone |
| Cat | Wet food | Ball |
| Dog | Treats | Chasing a squirel |
| Dog | Potatoe | Ball |
| Dog | Treats | Ball |
| ... | ... | ... |

Target table:

| Animal | Treats | Wet food | Potatoe | Fake Bone | Ball | Chasing a squirrel | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | ... |
| Cat | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... |

Since I'm basically starting from zero again, the only progress I've made is the following:

```
SELECT Animal, Digested, COUNT(*), Played with, COUNT(*) 
FROM TEST-TABLE
WHERE Animal IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Animal, Digested, Played with
ORDER BY Animal
```

This is obviously not the solution and I'm thankful for any input. The target table doesn't necessarily has to be identical to the one I've typed out above, but something that would count each activity per animal would be awesome!

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your target table, you wrote Dog + Ball = 3 - it should be 2 in my opinion. Either way, I just edit my answer to fit it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Link and code snippet.

You can use dynamic SQL, use [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/03eb05/2):

```
WITH distinct_activities AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT activity FROM (
        SELECT Digested AS activity FROM TEST_TABLE
        UNION
        SELECT Played_with AS activity FROM TEST_TABLE
    ) AS all_activities
),
pivot_query AS (
    SELECT
        'SELECT Animal, ' ||
        string_agg(
            'COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Digested = ''' || activity || ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) + ' ||
            'COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Played_with = ''' || activity || ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS ' || quote_ident(activity),
            ', '
        ) || '
        FROM TEST_TABLE
        GROUP BY Animal' AS query
    FROM distinct_activities
)
SELECT query FROM pivot_query;
```

The output of this will give you the query you need.